# sending emails from gmail with c++ code

Tags: c++, email, smtp, poco

I'm interested in sending emails with c++ code.

So far I've tried using the jwsmtp library at  jwsmtplib and I haven't had any real success.  Any suggestions?  Below is my code:

```
//code:
#include <iostream>
#include <jwsmtp/jwsmtp.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(  ) {

std::vector<char> vec;
std::string mess("Foo\nBar");
for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < mess.length( ); ++i)
  vec.push_back(mess[i]);


jwsmtp::mailer mail("me@gmail.com",              // who the mail is too
                  "sme@gmail.com",              // who the mail is from
                  "There is always room for FooBar",  // subject for the email
                  vec,                                // content of the message
                  "smtp.gmail.com",             // the smtp server to mail to
          465,      //jwsmtp::mailer::SMTP_PORT, // default smtp port (25)
                  false);                             // do not query MX records

mail.username("me@gmail.com");
mail.password("mepassword");


//mail.authtype(jwsmtp::mailer::PLAIN);
mail.send();

return 0;
}
```

I'm definitely open to other libraries or classes, but I'm constraint with OS X.

I've also download the POCO library as I've seen it mentioned in other threads, but I would prefer to have a flatter learning curve.  If anyone has example code with POCO I would appreciate getting a look.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use a lib that supports SSL as you can only send mail via gmail using an encrypted connection. I only know of Windows libs for this sadly.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem using C# on .NET, I had to use SSL over port 587 to make it work.

Comment: @ Rob I thought gmail could used with STL? No?  Anyways my code uses port 465.  Is it that jwsmtp can't be used with SSL?

Comment: @ferruccio but you where using the jwsmtp library?

Comment: no, I was using the .NET Framework Library

Comment: jwsmtp doesn't support SSL so you're still trying to send a plain unencrypted email over port 465, which is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [VMime](http://www.vmime.org/) library!